# After I have pressed ENTER, the program did not output any results. Why is this happening?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I saw this code online. After I have pressed ENTER, the program did not output any results.  Why is this happening? Could someone please help me out? thanks in advance for any help!

```
int main(){
    const string hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    cout << "enter a series of numbers between 0 and 15 separated by spaces. Hit ENTER when finished: " 
            << endl;
    string result;
    string::size_type n;
    while(cin >> n){
        if(n < hexdigits.size()){
            result += hexdigits[n];
        }
    }
    cout << "your hex number is: " << result << endl;
}
```

I have entered input:

```
12 0 5 15 8 15
```

Comment: Try pressing Ctrl+D,  it ends the input and should get the cin to fail

Comment: thanks for the advice!

Comment: The compiler has finished. You are executing *your program.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input loop will keep reading integers until either the input stream is closed, or something is encountered that cannot be parsed as an integer.  Each value is separated by *any* whitespace, which includes *newline*.

If you want to output something new for each *line* of input you can use `std::getline` to first read the line of characters, then read from a `std::istringstream`:

```
string line;
while( getline( cin, line ) )
{
    istringstream iss( line );

    string result;
    string::size_type n;
    while(iss >> n){
        if(n < hexdigits.size()){
            result += hexdigits[n];
        }
    }
    cout << "your hex number is: " << result << endl;
}
```